# Create empty dataframes in Google Sheets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, google-sheets

I am creating a web scraping program using python, BeautifulSoup, pandas and Google Sheets.
Up until now I have managed to scrape data tables from urls which I’m getting from a list in Google sheets - I have created data frames for each dataset. From my list of urls, some of the cells in the column is empty, which gives me the following error when I try to import the dataframes into another sheet:

> MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant
> http://?

What I’d like to achieve is, that for every cell that’s empty in the sheets with urls, I would like to create an empty dataframe, just like the ones with data inside them. Is that possible?

My code so far looks like this:

```
import gspread
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'credentials.json')

scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
        ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        )

gc = gspread.Client(auth=scoped_credentials)
gc.session = AuthorizedSession(scoped_credentials)
spreadsheet_key = gc.open_by_key('api_key')


# Data import
data_worksheet = spreadsheet_key.worksheet("Data")

# Url's
url_worksheet = spreadsheet_key.worksheet("Urls")

link_list = url_worksheet.col_values(2)


def get_info(linkIndex) :

    page = requests.get(link_list[linkIndex])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    try :
        tbl = soup.find('table')

        labels = [] 
        results = []

        for tr in tbl.findAll('tr'):
            headers = [th.text.strip()  for th in tr.findAll('th')]
            data = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.findAll('td')]
            labels.append(headers)
            results.append(data) 

        final_results = []

        for final_labels, final_data in zip(labels, results):
            final_results.append({'Labels': final_labels, 'Data': final_data})

        df = pd.DataFrame(final_results)

        df['Labels'] = df['Labels'].str[0]
        df['Data'] = df['Data'].str[0]

        indexNames = df[df['Labels'] == 'Links'].index
        df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)

        set_with_dataframe(data_worksheet, df, col=(linkIndex*6)+1, row=2, 
include_column_header=False)[1:]

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

for linkInd in range(len(link_list))[1:] :
    get_info(linkInd)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you mean by an empty dataframe. If that's dataframe containing no data, it can be created with statement `pd.DataFrame()`. If that's dataframe containing `np.NaN` / `None` values in same columns as other dataframes, it can be created from a dict:

```
import pandas as pd

# x is the amount of rows in dataframe
d = {
    'column1': [np.NaN] * x,
    'column2': [np.NaN] * x,
    'column3': [np.NaN] * x
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

In the beginning of `get_info()` function there should be a check added:

```
if link_list[linkIndex] is not None: # or if link_list[linkIndex] != '' (depending on format of an empty cell)
```

In `if` section should be placed already existing logic, in `else` section an empty dataframe should be created. Function `set_with_dataframe()` should be called after `if / else` statement, because it's executed in both cases.